# binning data live into a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, binning

I am calculating two distances and binning them in intervals of 0.1 in a 2D array. Currently I am doing this. However it takes a lot of time for large number of points

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import distance as d
dat=np.random.rand(100,3)
dd2d=np.zeros((10,10))
while len(dat)>0:
    i=len(dat)-1
    while i>0:
        dist0=d.euclidean(dat[0],dat[i])
        dist1=d.cosine(dat[0],dat[i])
        ind0=int(dist0/0.1)
        ind1=int(dist1/0.1)
        if ind0>9 or ind1>9:
            pass
        else:
            dd2d[ind0,ind1]+=1
        i-=1
    dat=np.delete(dat,0,axis=0)
    print len(dat)
```

What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Also how can I convert the `while` loops in my code into `for` loops so that I can add progressbar/tqdm to keep track of run time.

Comment: If your aim is speed, don't use `while` loops.  Don't use `for` loops.  And don't do this - `dist0/0.1` - dividing is way more slow than multiplying.  Do `dist0 * 10`.  What you want is to vectorize your loops into something that runs in compiles C-code.  Something like `pdist`

Comment: I am using a different function written in cython for calculating distances. So that part is optimised. Here given `scipy.spatial.distance` for illustrative purposes only

Comment: Should still be able to use `pdist(dat, lambda u, v: myUFunc(u,v))`.  Although if your distance function is vectorized you could also do `dist0 = myUFunc(dat[i], dat[j])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are already importing `scipy.spatial.distance`, might as well use `pdist`.  And then you're just making a 2d histogram.  Use `np.histogram2d`.

```
def binDists2d(dat, f1 = 'euclidean', f2 = 'cosine'):
    dist0 = d.pdist(dat, f1)
    dist1 = d.pdist(dat, f2)
    rng = np.array([[0, 1], [0, 1]])
    return np.histogram2d(dist0, dist1, bins = 10, range = rng)
```

`pdist` only returns the upper triangular elements.  If you want to do this manually, use `np.triu_indices`, which you could use to generate the distances if `scipy` is unavailable.

```
def cosdist(u, v):
    return 1 - u.dot(v) / (np.linalg.norm(u) * np.linlg.norm(v))

def binDists2d(dat, f0 = lambda u, v: np.linalg.norm(u - v), f1 = cosdist):
    i, j = np.triu_indices(dat.shape[0], 1)
    dist0 = f0(dat[i], dat[j])
    dist1 = f1(dat[i], dat[j])
    rng = np.array([[0, 1], [0, 1]])
    return np.histogram2d(dist0, dist1, bins = 10, range = rng)
```

**EDIT:** Less memory-hungry version:

```
def binDists2d(dat, f0, f1, n = 1, bins = 10, rng = np.array([[0, 1], [0, 1]])):
    i_, j_ = np.triu_indices(dat.shape[0], 1)
    out = np.zeros((bins, bins))
    i_, j_ = np.array_split(i_, n), np.array_split(j_, n)
    for k, (i, j) in enumerate(zip(i_, j_)):
        dist0 = f0(dat[i], dat[j])
        dist1 = f1(dat[i], dat[j])
        out += np.histogram2d(dist0, dist1, bins = bins, range = rng)
        print(str(k) + " of " + str(n) + "completed")
    return out
```

Comment: `---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-238-f81d36e3b407> in <module>()
----> 1 binDists2d(dat)

<ipython-input-237-b9685d10b4d4> in binDists2d(dat, f1, f2)
      3     dist1 = d.pdist(dat, f2)
      4     i, j = np.triu_indices(dat.shape[0], 1)
----> 5     return np.histogram2d(dist0[i, j], dist1[i, j], bins = 10)

IndexError: too many indices for array`

Comment: I get Indexerror for `dat=np.random.rand(10,3)` running with `binDists2d`function you gave

Comment: Whoops, `pdist` now outputs the upper triangular natively.  That's handy.

Comment: Now that works and lightning fast too... I will test this on my main data and report... For now I am accepting this as the answer. although I have no means to track how much progress this function has made... for high no. of data points (I have about 0.1M) it might take lot of time executing

Comment: If you overrun your RAM, check out [`np.memmap`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) and try writing the `dist` arrays to disk, and then creating a stack of `histogram2d` outputs from managably-sized chunks of the distance data which you can sum together at the end.

Comment: Yeah, you're going to have about 40GB in each `dist` array if they are `float64`.  You'll probably need to use my second function, iterate over indices like `i_ = np.array_split(i, n)` and build `n` histograms to sum at the end.

Comment: I just successfully crashed by i7-16GB MBP :) did well with 100k points using in-built distances. With custom functions however, it crashed right away... Will look at `np.memmap` now!

Comment: Try the less memory-hungry version.  Start with about  `n=100` and see how it works

Comment: Also make sure that your ufunc works with a smaller data set first.

Comment: I am getting `ValueError: Input vector should be 1-D.` from `dist0 = f0(dat[i], dat[j])` line of the less memory-hungry version. I think `np.array_split` is creating an array in place of `j`. I was unable to resolve the issue.

Comment: Will try different options today...will post one tomorrow...You helped a long way through... Thank you so much! :)